# the event slideDown was not work correctly

Tags: slidedown

i have problem in slideDown mehod.

the event slideDown was not work correctly...
when i click the button to run slideDown mehod this half opens and fast close:(
this page is for password recovery and use PasswordRecovery

```
<asp:Content ID="Content2" ContentPlaceHolderID="js" runat="server">
        <script type="text/javascript">
            $(document).ready(function () {
                $(".passrecovery-btn").click(function () {
                    $("#pass-error").slideDown('slow'); 
                });
            });
        </script>
    </asp:Content>
    <asp:Content ID="Content3" ContentPlaceHolderID="ContentPlaceHolder1" runat="server">
        <div class="page-content">
            <div class="password-recovery">
                <div class="identify-account">
                    <h1 class="identify">Identify Your Account</h1>
                    <hr />
                </div>
                <asp:PasswordRecovery ID="PassRecovery" runat="server">
                    <QuestionTemplate>
                        <table cellpadding="1" cellspacing="0" style="border-collapse:collapse;">
                            <tr>
                                <td>
                                    <table cellpadding="0">
                                        <tr>
                                            <td align="center" colspan="2">
                                                Identity Confirmation</td>
                                        </tr>
                                        <tr>
                                            <td align="center" colspan="2">
                                                Answer the following question to receive your password.</td>
                                        </tr>
                                        <tr>
                                            <td align="right">
                                                User Name:</td>
                                            <td>
                                                <asp:Literal ID="UserName" runat="server"></asp:Literal>
                                            </td>
                                        </tr>
                                        <tr>
                                            <td align="right">
                                                Question:</td>
                                            <td>
                                                <asp:Literal ID="Question" runat="server"></asp:Literal>
                                            </td>
                                        </tr>
                                        <tr>
                                            <td align="right">
                                                <asp:Label ID="AnswerLabel" runat="server" AssociatedControlID="Answer">Answer:</asp:Label>
                                            </td>
                                            <td>
                                                <asp:TextBox ID="Answer" runat="server"></asp:TextBox>
                                                <asp:RequiredFieldValidator ID="AnswerRequired" runat="server" 
                                                    ControlToValidate="Answer" ErrorMessage="Answer is required." 
                                                    ToolTip="Answer is required." ValidationGroup="PassRecovery">*</asp:RequiredFieldValidator>
                                            </td>
                                        </tr>
                                        <tr>
                                            <td align="center" colspan="2" style="color:Red;">
                                                <asp:Literal ID="FailureText" runat="server" EnableViewState="False"></asp:Literal>
                                            </td>
                                        </tr>
                                        <tr>
                                            <td align="right" colspan="2">
                                                <asp:Button ID="SubmitButton" runat="server" CommandName="Submit" Text="Submit" 
                                                    ValidationGroup="PassRecovery" CssClass="passrecovery-btn" />
                                            </td>
                                        </tr>
                                    </table>
                                </td>
                            </tr>
                        </table>
                    </QuestionTemplate>
                    <UserNameTemplate>
                        <table cellpadding="1" cellspacing="0" style="border-collapse:collapse;">
                            <tr>
                                <td>
                                    <table cellpadding="0">
                                        <tr>
                                            <td align="center" colspan="2">
                                                Forgot Your Password?</td>
                                        </tr>
                                        <tr>
                                            <td align="center" colspan="2">
                                                Enter your User Name to receive your password.</td>
                                        </tr>
                                        <tr>
                                            <td align="right">
                                                <asp:Label ID="UserNameLabel" runat="server" AssociatedControlID="UserName">User Name:</asp:Label>
                                            </td>
                                            <td>
                                                <asp:TextBox ID="UserName" runat="server"></asp:TextBox>
                                                <asp:RequiredFieldValidator ID="UserNameRequired" runat="server" 
                                                    ControlToValidate="UserName" ErrorMessage="User Name is required." 
                                                    ToolTip="User Name is required." ValidationGroup="PassRecovery">*</asp:RequiredFieldValidator>
                                            </td>
                                        </tr>
                                        <tr>

                                            <td align="right" colspan="2">
                                                <asp:Button ID="SubmitButton" runat="server" CommandName="Submit" Text="Submit" 
                                                    ValidationGroup="PassRecovery" CssClass="passrecovery-btn" />
                                            </td>
                                        </tr>
                                        <tr>
                                            <td align="center" colspan="2" style="color:Red;">
                                                <div class="pass-error" id="pass-error"><asp:Literal ID="FailureText" runat="server" EnableViewState="False"></asp:Literal></div>
                                            </td>
                                        </tr>
                                </table>
                                <div class="loading">
                                    <img src="../Static/images/Loadloading.gif" width="16" height="11" alt="" />
                                </div>
                            </tr>
                        </table>
                    </UserNameTemplate>
                </asp:PasswordRecovery>
            </div>
    </div>
    </asp:Content>



                    Css:

                    div.password-recovery
                    {
                        border:1px solid #333;
                        width:300px;
                        margin:0px auto;
                        text-align:center;
                        padding:30px 60px 0px 60px;
                        margin-top:30px;
                        font-family: 'lucida grande', tahoma, verdana, arial, sans-serif;
                        font-size: 12px;
                        border-radius:5px;
                        overflow:visible;
                    }

                    div.pass-error{display:none;border:1px solid black;border-radius:5px;}
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to set the display of the object that you want to slide down to none in the css like so

```
.passrecovery-btn {
          display: none;
}
```